# How to start a function if its less then a number and more then a number

Tags: javascript, html, function

Can someone help me? What’s supposed to happen is that its supposed to get the user’s first, last name, and made up number more then 3 less then 1000. Display it on the web page and if the first + last name is less then 20 and the made up number is more then 3 and less then 1000, the function is going to start, if it’s invalid then alert the user.

```js
function startLoop(){
      var currTime = 50;
      for(i=50; i>=0; i=i-5) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          if(currTime != 0){
            document.write("Time remaining: " + currTime + "<br>");
          }
          if (currTime <= 25 && currTime!=0){
            document.write("less then 25 seconds left <br>");y
          } else if(currTime==0){
            document.write("blast off");
          }

          currTime = currTime - 5;
        }, 1000*i);
      }
    }

    function start(){
        var vari = document.getElementById(input).value;
        var vari2 = document.getElementById(input2).value;
        var badge = document.getElementById(input3).value;

        document.write(vari + vari2);
        document.write(badge);

        var sum = vari + vari2;
        if(sum < 20){
            if(badge > 3 && badge < 1000){
                startLoop();
            }else {
                alert("Please re-enter your badge number");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please re-enter your name")
        }

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Jeffrey Payne-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>UAT Space Program</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="UATSpace.png" />
    <h1>UAT Space Program</h1>
    <p>Test of the paragraph tags</p>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <input type="text" id="input2"/>
    <input type="text" id="input3"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an error. The getElementById's reference needs to be in quotes.ex :  document.getElementById("input")

Comment: "_if the first + last name is less then 20_" Are the names really numbers ..?

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track in creating the logic.
When debugging, try to use your web browser's console and see what went wrong. 
In your case, your code for `document.getElementById('input').value;` is missing quotation marks. Also, if you want to know the length of strings, use `.length` property because using `vari + vari2` for example results in the string being combined / concatenated.

Here's the proper function:

```js
function start(){
    var vari = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var vari2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    var badge = document.getElementById('input3').value;

    document.write(vari + vari2);
    document.write(badge);

    var sum = vari.length + vari2.length; // get the sum of the inputs

    if(sum < 20){
        if(badge > 3 && badge < 1000){
            startLoop();
        }else {
            alert("Please re-enter your badge number");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please re-enter your name")
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Jeffrey Payne-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>UAT Space Program</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="UATSpace.png" />
    <h1>UAT Space Program</h1>
    <p>Test of the paragraph tags</p>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <input type="text" id="input2"/>
    <input type="text" id="input3"/>
    <button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>  
  </body>
</html>
```